# Зачем Code Review существует отдельно от Stack Overflow и чем они вообще отличаются?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, инспекция-кода

Зачем нужен сайт [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), когда есть сайт [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). В чём принципиальное отличие двух сайтов?

Answer (score 18):

Codereview, как это ни странно, для предоставления ревью (проверок) работающего кода. В то время как StackOverflow для разрешения тех или иных проблем программистов. Применимо к StackOverflow на русском такого различия пока не делается, так как нет сайта Codereview на русском. Поэтому здесь разрешены вопросы проверок кода с использованием специальной метки [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0).

Answer (score 8):

Изначально был только Stack Overflow. Постепенно он дорос до точки, когда все эти околопрограммерские темы можно было выделить в отдельные подсайты, что они и сделали.

Есть также https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Для решения программерских пазлов https://codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Сейчас Stack Overflow позиционируется именно как сайт для вопросов чисто по программированию.

Answer (score 1):

Немного добавлю к существующим замечательным ответам, так как имею немного опыта как на StackOverflow, так и на CodeReview StackExchange порталах.

CodeReview сайт существует исключительно для ревью **работающего кода**, с четким описанием того, что этот код делает. На сайте достаточно строгие требования к новым вопросам - код должен быть Ваш, он должен быть приведен внутри ответа (сейчас даже [добавили жесткое требование в форму нового вопроса](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9038/24208)), к коду должна быть приложена минимальная документация, а также, желательно, пример использования.

На StackOverflow же, подобные вопросы по работающему коду будут достаточно быстро закрыты и, если повезет, мигрированы на CodeReview модератором. И, если повезет, Вам не скажут, что Вы должны почитать мануал использования сайта, и вообще, какой вы нехороший человек, что такое спросили (не мог удержаться не mock SO, сорри).

---

На самом деле очень советую пробовать контрибьютать в CodeReview - это совершенно уникальное место, где можно научиться совсем по-другому смотреть на код, узнать много новых перфоманс и синтаксических трюков, а также, вообще, в целом, <s>понять и простить</s> понимать и принимать здравую критику.

Comment: «немного опыта» ... особенно на SO, видим, видим :) А тут так и вовсе [новичок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joN2T.jpg).